# Adding an event listener to a procedurally assigned attribute on a single page application

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application, addeventlistener, setattribute

I'm writing a single page note application in JavaScript with no libraries. The app lets the user add a note, and shows a shortened form beneath the input.

When they want to see the full text of their note, they can click on the relevant note to expand it.

So far, the input notes are saved in an array, then written in a shortened version (presented in HTML list elements), which have the array position assigned to them as an ID (assigning an index variable as the array length -1, then setting it as an attribute)

The view code is

```
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <script src='./note.js'></script>
      <script src='./controller.js'></script>
      <title>JS Notes</title>
    </head>

    <body>

      <h1 id="title">JS Notes</h1>


      <textarea id="input"></textarea><br>
      <button id="create">Create</button>

      <ul id="note area"></ul>


    </body>
  </html>
```

The controller code is

```
window.onload = function() {
  var note, createButton;
  note = new Note;

  createButton = document.getElementById("create")
  createButton.addEventListener("click", processNote)

  function processNote(){
    var input, output, index, newLI;

    input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    note.addNote(input);
    index = note.showFullNote().length - 1
    document.getElementById('input').value = ""
    newLI = document.createElement('li');
    newLI.setAttribute("id", index)
    output = input.substring(0,20)
    newLI.appendChild(document.createTextNode(output + "..."))
    document.getElementById('note area').appendChild(newLI)
  }
```

The model for processing notes

```
(function(exports) {
    function Note() {
        this._list = new Array;
    };

    Note.prototype.addNote = function(input) {
        this._list.push(input)
    };

    Note.prototype.showFullNote = function() {
        return this._list
    };

    exports.Note = Note;
})(this);
```

I was trying to add an event listener for clicking on the list element, and passing the id of that element as the index number.

I thought this could be done by `getElementsByTag`, but I'm not sure how to then take the index of a specifically clicked list item, rather than the first list item on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add the event listener to the `li` element before you append it to the note area.

```
newLI.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let elementId = e.id;
  // any other logic here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it sent me in the right direction.

What I found was that `elementId` in your example was returning as undefined, as `e` was being passed into the function as the full MouseEvent object.

To get to the id number, I needed to access the MouseEvent path array:

`let elementId =  e.path[0].id`